# Maven Java Project Only Working Once

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I imported a project into Netbeans and opened one of the examples. When I first ran it, the program worked just fine. However, the second time I ran it I got the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project webcam-capture-example-qrcode: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

If this isn't normal then it is probably how I've imported the project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is either in your `pom.xml` file or in the class that you are running.

If it worked the first time, then maybe you are inadvertently running a different main, or you changed some configuration.

The log  you report says that the command exited  with an error, maybe the program is running as expected, and has an internal error, for instance it cannot access the resource that it needs (a webcam?) and that was instead available the first time you ran it.

Always run `clean and build` to make sure there are no spurious files around and look into the stack-trace to get the real error.

Comment: There seems to be some problem in the oss-parent-2.pom file. The full stack-trace said that lots of these maven plugins are missing. The first time I run a project (and it works), it comes up with the same messages but also says:
It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.

For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
It says this on other builds but doesn't actually work that time.

Comment: this is a good catch. Have you copied the pom file from somewhere? Can we see it?

Comment: I didn't copy it, although Netbeans may have copied the file. When I build and compile the file Netbeans seems to be making a new pom file (this oss-parent-2.pom). When I run it, it uses the pom file from the project. Nonetheless, either way it doesn't work